# Class not found - Avro with Camel

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, apache-camel, avro

I am using avro schema from: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html#Defining+a+schema 
I have used the avro-tools-1.8.1.jar to create the User class from the schema. The schema is under src/main/resources/avro and the user generated class is under src/main/java/avro.
I have a simple route

```
(and I tried to load the schema from dir as well)

AvroDataFormat format = new AvroDataFormat(User.getClassSchema());
from("topic1")
 .marshal(format)
 .to("topic2")
```

I have tried to use:

```
.marshal().avro().to("topic2")
```

but not success.

I got "ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord"

I don't understand what I am missing, it should work with marhsal().avro(), or marshal().avro(schema), I can see that the schema is loaded correctly.
I have followed this example:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-avro/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/dataformat/avro/AvroGenericMarshaAndUnmarshaTest.java

Comment: Hi, Could you please log the body of from("topic1"), to see the data incoming.

Comment: The data is coming through: BodyType: byte[], Body: {"user": { "name": "TestUser",            "favorite_number": 19,"favorite_color": "red"}}]. I am debugging the camel code, when it tries to get the field "name", it crashes. I don't know if I should convert the body to another type

Comment: Hi, put it in a processor and try to convert it into a ByteBuffer as seen in this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56477058/class-not-found-avro-with-camel

Comment: So I tried until now to convert, either using a processor or calling .convertBodyTo(), but I have the same error, with the different class: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord. I think I need to convert to smth that can be cast to IndexedRecord

Comment: my problem is in GenericData:  public Object getField(Object record, String name, int position) {
    return ((IndexedRecord)record).get(position);
  }

Comment: What I did was: I have used https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter and called convertToGenericDataRecord() I have passed my exchange body and after that I have set the new body (for the exchange) as a GenericData.Record, in this way the marshaling worked. But now I cannot see why should I use the marshal from the camel instead I can call convertToAvro and send the result to my topic.

Comment: I saw that even in the github example from camel, the data is send as a GenericData.Record, but I thought that this will be done by the camel.